# Google Admin SDK Directory API acts weird since today (2014/02/13)

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Turns out that today methods **get** and **list** return different givenName, familyName and fullName of a given user if that particular user has a G+ profile with a different name.

EDIT: To be clear: **get** method returns the usual names but **list** method returns G+ names.

Has anybody else seen this behaviour?

You can try it using the APIs Explorer (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users)

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Strange...

Comment: I've opened an issue (http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3533). I don't know if SO tag "google-api" or that issue tracker are actively watched by Google, but I think it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved on February 28th.